# Sudoku input program skipping a prompt

Tags: c++, sudoku

I wrote a program for my computer science class that validates and solves sudoku puzzles from .txt files, but I wanted to take it one step further and write a program that made it easy to input and sudoku game. I'm sure you can figure out the format of the files based on this code. My only problem is that the last cin gets skipped, and that option is important to me. Any insight will be appreciated!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct s {
s();
~s() {/*zzzz*/}
void show_grid();
void set (int &r, int &c, int &v) {g[r][c] = v;}
private:
int g[9][9];
};

//************************************************************************

void s::show_grid() {

//print game out to check it
cout << "  |  -------------------------------  |" << endl;
for (int k=0; k<81; k++) {
    if (k%3 == 0)
        cout << "  |";
    cout << "  " << g[k/9][k%9];
    if (k%9 == 8) {
        cout << "  |" << endl;
        if ((k/9)%3 == 2)
            cout << "  |  -------------------------------  |" << endl;
    }
}
cout << endl;
}

//************************************************************************

s::s() {

//initialize all elements to zero
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
        g[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
}

//************************************************************************

void create_name (string &name) {

//append .txt extension LIKE IT OR NOT
string ext = name;
ext.erase(ext.begin(), ext.end() - 4);

if (ext.compare(".txt")!=0)
    name.append(".txt");
}

//************************************************************************

int main () {

s g;
string name;
string yon("");
int count = 0;
int row, col, val, rcv;
ofstream os;

cout << "Enter game file name: ";
cin >> name;

create_name(name);

//open and do typical checks
os.open(name.c_str());
if (os.fail()) {
    cerr << "Could not create " << name << ". Waaaah waaaaaaaaaah...\n\n";
    return 0;
}

//useful output (hopefully)
cout << "Enter grid coordinates and value as a 3-digit number,\n"
    << "from left to right, row by row.\n" 
    << "(e.g. 2 in first box would be 112)\n";

//take input as one int, to be user friendly
while (cin >> rcv && count < 81) {
    row = (rcv / 100) - 1;
    col = ((rcv / 10) % 10) - 1;
    val = rcv % 10;
    os << row << " " << col << " " << val << endl;
    g.set (row, col, val);
    count++;
}

os.close();

//From here down is broken, but it still compiles, runs, and works
cout << "Show grid input(y/n)?\n";
cin >> yon;

if (yon.compare("y")==0)
    g.show_grid();
else if (yon.compare("n")==0)
    cout << "Peace!\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you terminate the `while` loop? Do you actually type in 81 numbers?

Comment: Oh I guess that's pretty important, I simply enter any char which terminates the loop because it isn't an int. The 81 is to prevent the user from overstepping the bounds of the array

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You intentionally create an error condition on `cin` -- no further input operation can succeed until you call `.clear()` *and* read the odd character in.

Comment: gotcha, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
//useful output (hopefully)
cout << "Enter grid coordinates and value as a 3-digit number,\n"
    << "from left to right, row by row.\n" 
    << "(e.g. 2 in first box would be 112)\n"
    << "or Z to end the loop\n";  // 1

//take input as one int, to be user friendly
while (count < 81 && cin >> rcv ) { // 2
    row = (rcv / 100) - 1;
    col = ((rcv / 10) % 10) - 1;
    val = rcv % 10;
    os << row << " " << col << " " << val << endl;
    g.set (row, col, val);
    count++;
}

if(!std::cin) {  // 3
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

1) Let the user know that he can enter in invalid char. It doesn't have to be `Z`, actually **any** non-numeric char will work.

2) Fix off-by-one error in the order of the `&&`.

3) If `std::cin` is in error state, clear the error and ignore the `Z`.

Comment: Exactly! This is what I'm needing to do. Did you just add the std scopes to get your point across? Also, is the STL ignore() just for good measure? If you were going to clear cin anyways, would that not just be accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: 1) I added `std::` because I teach people never to use `using namespace std;`. 2) The `ignore()` is required. 3) Even after you clear the error condition, the `Z` will still be in the input stream and must be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while (cin >> rcv && count < 81)
```

Consider what happens when `count==81`: First, `rcv` will be input from `cin`, and only then the condition `count < 81` will be evaluated to false. The loop will stop, and the value of `rcv` will be ignored. So effectively you read one input too many.

You should change the order of evaluation, so that `count` is checked first:

```
while (count < 81 && cin >> rcv)
```

---

**Edit**:

According to your comment above you are actually expecting to read less than 81 values. In that case, I recommend having the user input a special value (for example, 0) to terminate the loop. You'd just need to add `if (rcv==0) break;`. If you just input an invalid value as you are apparently doing, the `cin` stream will be put in a failed state and further input will not succeed.

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be to do simply `while ( cin >> rcv )`, and then check that you haven't entered too many (or too few, with a check after the loop).

Comment: @JamesKanze: But the program accepts more input after the 81 values, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that.  Since he's inputting 81 values, it seemed obvious that the program was designed to read from a file; no one inputs 81 values manually.

Comment: Ay boys, this program only creates a file. The program I wrote that reads in files is totally separate.

Comment: @dockleryxk: Now that I see your comment above I think I understand what you're actually trying to do, see my edit.

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't like having to set a specific input like that

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> yon
```

still actually reads in a variable, it just reads in the variable that the while loop found to be false. When the while loop condition returns false rcv is ignored, so the number remains in the input stream waiting for the next cin statement. When yon is called that number meant for rcv is read into yon, giving you some strange errors.

it would be better to use interjay's method:

```
while (count < 81 && cin >> rcv)
```

Comment: Hmm well I'm not trying to input 81 variables, because I'm trying to input a puzzle that's yet to be solved, so the empty indices will be zeroes

Comment: so how does this effect the loop i proposed? the loop will continue to run and read in the next variable until it finds count to be over 81.

Comment: Because less than 81 variables get input, but it absolutely can't be more than 81 digits. This is because Sudoku games have given values to begin with